# PHPExcel set cell value dynamically

Tags: php, sql-server, phpexcel

**This is my code of getting the data of my excel file...**

```
    require_once 'IOFactory.php';
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("NAV USER ACCESS Calculation.xlsx"); 
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(2);

    $worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

    $worksheetTitle     = $worksheet->getTitle();
    $highestRow         = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
    $highestColumn      = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'
    $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
    $nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;
    echo '<div id="table-cont">
        <table border="1">';
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row)
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col)
        {
            $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
            $val = $cell->getValue();
            $val =$cell->getCalculatedValue();
            $val =$cell->getFormattedValue();

            $dataType = PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::dataTypeForValue($val);
            echo '<td>' . $val . '</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>
        <div id="clock"></div>
        </div>';
```

**And this is my code of setting my table into excel, but i dont know whats wrong...**

```
    $serverName="192.168.1.253";
    $conInfo=array("Database"=>"dbName","UID"=>"sa","PWD"=>"xxxxx");
    $con= sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$conInfo);

    require_once 'IOFactory.php';
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("NAV USER ACCESS Calculation.xlsx"); 
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(2);

    $worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

    $worksheetTitle     = $worksheet->getTitle();
    $highestRow         = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
    $highestColumn      = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'
    $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
    $nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;
    echo '<div id="table-cont">
        <table border="1">';
    $sql= sqlsrv_query($con,"SELECT * FROM dbo.[Active Session]");
    while($data=sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row)
        {
            echo '<tr>';
            for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col)
            {
                $cell = $worksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
                $val = $cell->getValue();
                $val =$cell->getCalculatedValue();
                $val =$cell->getFormattedValue();

                $dataType = PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::dataTypeForValue($val);
                echo '<td>' . $val . '</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    }
    echo '</table>
        <div id="clock"></div>
        </div>';
```

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: i want to insert all data in my table to my excel file

Comment: Are you trying to generate HTML output at the same time as writing to an Excel file? Are you trying to append new data to an existing file that already contains data?

Comment: no, i just want to update my existing excel file, i just want like copy all data in my table and paste it in my excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be as simple as

```
$worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

$highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow() + 1;
$sql= sqlsrv_query($con,"SELECT * FROM dbo.[Active Session]");
while($data=sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $worksheet->fromArray($data, null, 'A' . $highestRow++);
}
```

And then save the file again afterwards

Comment: how to insert that? T_T

Comment: Then do some basic debugging to make sure that your query is actually returning data